# Custom CKeditor plugin on Joomla installation

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, joomla1.5

I have written a plugin for CKeditor according to this tutorial: [Plugin Tutorial](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials) but I can't get it shown on the ckeditor's toolbar of my Joomla 1.5 installation. I have copied it in the plugins folder, registered it in the config.js as an extra plugin, even tried the Advanced Configuration in the backend settings by setting this: **CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'myplugin';** or this **config.extraPlugins = 'myplugin'** but nothing happens, no button whatsoever. Can someone list the "installation procedure" of the plugin on a joomla 1.5 system? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to have an entry in the jos_plugins table.  Unless I'm building an installation package for it, I just copy a similar record and make the changes to match my plugin - be sure to get the value in the "folder" correct.